# command Add-AdlAnalyticsDataSource not found

Tags: azure-powershell

I have a deployment script & I have to give it to operations team to deploy ADLA & add Azure Storage data source to ADLA. 
This command works well on my local machine as well as our development vm.

Operations team facing issues with this command. The command Add-AdlAnalyticsDataSource not found. They are using plain windows server virtual machine for deployment having Powershell version 3.4.0
Are we missing anything?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rohi_Dev_1.0 What is the Windows Management framework installed on your machine?

This can be checked using **$PSVersionTable** command.
 If the PSVersion is below 5.0, then Install-Module command won’t be available in showcommand window

Comment: This Add-AdlAnalyticsDataSource command is available in and above Windows Management framework 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we should upgrade your Azure PowerShell version to 4.3.0, here is my PowerShell output, it works for me:

[image]

If you want to upgrade your PowerShell version, we can download PowerShell installation package from this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v4.3.1-August2017/azure-powershell.4.3.1.msi).

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: @Rohi_Dev_1.0 Do you mean you have update Azure PowerShell to latest version still does not work?

Comment: Sorry, it will work. But I don't want to upgrade Power Shell version actually. If I will upgrade PowerShell version then I have to upgrade my other commands & it will be a huge change in my deployment. I just wonder If it's working on my machine with same PowerShell Version then why it's not working on VM.

Comment: I got the difference. I think with the Windows Management framework it will work. Suggested by @Amruta in above answer

Comment: @Rohi_Dev_1.0 ok, please try it. Please let me know if you need more help:)